# how to simulate 1000 concurrent user using jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, load, jmeter

Is that possible to simulate 1000 to 10000 user to jmeter?

If so how?

in 1 thread group only test 1k user:

Thread user = 1000,
Ramp up = 10 ,is this means it will test 1000 user in 10sec?,
Loopcount = 1, is there a disadvantage if I put 10 here ,is this means 1000x10 user = it will simulate 10k user?

Is 1 thread group can simulate 1000 concurrent user?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I could have written it as comment, but it went out of characters.

definitions given by @Quality-Expert are correct but his understanding of your test setup is wrong.

**10 loop count doesnt mean 1000*10**

It means at a given moment only 1000 concurrent users will be present but they will perform same action 10 times. It doesn't mean 10000 users.

**Rampup is 10 doesnt mean 1000 users for 10 seconds**

It means 100 users will come online in 1 second and next 100 users will online in next second i.e. in 2 seconds 200 users will come online and this is how 1000 users will come online in 10 seconds.

If you dont provide any test duration test will end their itself, it wont continue after threads have finished their task. If you want to load test with 1000 users then provide some test duration i.e. 10 mintues. Thus test will run with 1000 concurrent users for 10 min. Rampup is just warm up time for system under load test so that it wont face sudden load of 1000 users.

About 10000 load, use need to use distributed set of machines/client of Jmeter which will generate that load or use cloud load testing tools.

Comment: Note: To utilize `Duration` feature of Thread Group Scheduler one needs to provide `work` to the Thread Group. The easiest way of doing  so is to set `Loop Count` as `Forever`.

Answer (score 5):

Number of Threads- The maximum number of users you want to run.

Ramp-Up Period - Defines how long it takes for JMeter to ramp up from zero users to  X number of threads. It is in terms of seconds.

Loop Count - Defines how many times you want each user to run your script.

Other thing is that No. of user depends on your machine CPU , RAM , Physical memory. As far as I know using normal system you can user 250-500 max. users.

If you want to do testing like 1k,10k users then you will have to use cloud systems like Neoload.

As per your given example , you are right about if you put thread user = 1000 & ramp up = 10 then it will run test till 10 seconds for 1000 users.

Let me know if you have still any confusion.

Comment: my system environment runs in i5 3.1Ghz-quadcore with 4gb ram memory. i run a 2000 = thread user with ramp = 1 and loop count = 1 , when i run the jmeter it stop on 1744 user , is the specs of my pc stops the test?and is the result is that accurate for a 1000 user test?

Comment: System will stop work when its capacity reaches. Till that capacity all result is accurate. For example if you system stops working when test reaches at 1000 user then till that 1000 user your load test report is correct so do not worry.

Comment: I'll let you know what my i7-8700 32GB RAM PC can do ;-)

Comment: @JaroslavŠtreit: showing off in advance? just let him or us know first.

Comment: I am able to generate up to 1600 VUs effectively. Then is problem with tested app... I will try to use different app or prepare some dummy.

Comment: @JaroslavŠtreit - Sure.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer for the above question in below screen, in Jmeter manual its different which says threads/ramp-up period= user per seconds