# Jmeter deviation vs throughput

Tags: testing, load, jmeter, throughput, deviation

can you give some.explanation on how to interpret deviation vs.throughput?
Is 1000++ deviation result means a poor performance of web under test?
And how can you also say that the web under test performs good? Is it base on.throughput result? How?

And what listener is the best for tracing the load/performance of a thousand users

Lastly is that possible to check the cpu/ram usage of the server while pwrforming the test

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Standard deviation quantifies how much response time varies around its mean, or average. It is not advisable to judge the system performance based on Standard Deviation. In reality this gives how much system is fluctuating. Deviations should be minimum i.e. less than 5%.
- ***Thoughput*** is defined as number of requests processed per second.
- It is better to use ***Throughput*** as a factor to judge system/application performance. Higher throughput means good system performance but again this depends on your choice. For some critical systems low response time is more required than high throughput. Throughput simply states that how much concurrent transactions your system can process per second which might mean high response time. if response time increases beyond a certain limit then that system is considered for performance tuning.

some systems Throughput means

- You can either use ***Summary Report*** or ***Aggregate Report*** listeners.
- **cpu/ram usage**, you can use "jp@gc - Perfmon Metrics collector" from Jmeter Plugin.

Hope this will help.

Comment: is there a benchmark for reading throughput result so i can say a web under test performs good. can you also help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887644/how-to-simulate-1000-concurrent-user-using-jmeter

Comment: i want to clarify if runs 100 users then the result of the graph listener is throughput = 675.068/per minute , why does the throughput excess on my thread user? sorry for too many question im new to load test

Comment: It depends on your scenario, 1 user can send "n" HTTP requests which includes redirection. Throughput is how many request, sent by 1 user were processed on per second/minute basis. So coming to ***throughput = 675.068/per minute*** which means approx ***11 requests/second***, which is quite slow. Refer this link to understand the concept of throughput http://www.joecolantonio.com/2011/07/05/performance-testing-what-is-throughput/

Comment: @JmeterPerfTest, Is there something we need to install in the server to be able to use Permon Metrics Collector?