# How to test performance with 1 million users in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I'd like to know how to test a website performance in Jmeter with up to 1 million active users, all accessing the site at the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to simulate 1000 concurrent user using jmeter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887644/how-to-simulate-1000-concurrent-user-using-jmeter)

Answer (score 2):

Given you have enough machines you can use as load generators it is not a problem to set up JMeter for such load.

Mind the following:

1. Most likely you won't be able to produce such a load from a single host so consider running JMeter in [distributed mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) when one JMeter master orchestrates X slaves which act as load generators.
2. JMeter default configuration is not suitable for high loads, it is good for scripts development and debugging only. Follow recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/nine-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide to get the most of your JMeter instances
3. Real users don't hammer application non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations and this "think time" can vary from several seconds to even several minutes (i.e. my browser doesn't send many requests to Stackoverflow while I'm typing this answer) so consider using [JMeter Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to mimic this "think time"
4. Make sure you add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan. Well-behaved browsers request "heavy" resources from web pages (like images, styles, scripts, etc.) only once, on subsequent request this stuff is being returned from the browser cache. You should simulate the same behaviour elsewise your load won't be realistic.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by having Jmeter in combination with a Virtual Server Hosting solution.

One way would be to setup multiple E2C machines in AWS and configure them so they each generate load using a load generation tool (like Apache JMeter) on a specific web application.

When you combine enough virtual load generators, you could reach 1 million virtual users (who probably get blocked by a Web Application Firewall or similar on the Application Under Test).

Information on [Amazon EC2 - Resizable Compute Capacity in The Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).