# Hardware configuration to run 200 users for Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Hi guys I want to run a test ( load test) with almost 200 users. I needed to know the exact hardware configuration I would require like : RAM, disk space, and all. 
Can someone help me on this....thanks in Advance.

(P.S : please don't tell me it depends on your user and all I'm new to Jmeter I don't know anything)

Comment: read there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887644/how-to-simulate-1000-concurrent-user-using-jmeter, there are some figures.

Comment: But I just want to run 200 users not 1000 users and that too in cmd...

Comment: They are using a  i5 3.1Ghz-quadcore with 4gb ram memory. It is a commodity machine. If you want to use mini-machines, I guess you'll have to benchmark by yourself.

Comment: "it depends on your user" is the only correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it depends on what your test is doing, number of [Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), number of [PreProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions), request and response size, etc.

Minimal configuration would be:

1. At least 512KB per thread + around 100 megabytes for JMeter to operate which gives ~100 MB of RAM
2. At least ~50 MB of disk space (JMeter)  + ~400 MB for Java SDK/JRE + how many extra space you need for test data and test results

However only you can get the exact answer by running your actual test and measuring the JMeter's footprint using i.e. [JVisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html) or [JMeter PerfMon](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) Plugin

Also make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Answer (score 0):

@Mehvish It is impossible to say the correct hardware requirement. But, a normal machines of this generation might support it. But, only way to validate is to actually do it.

Please refer this article as it has some good info which might help.
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15178/what-is-recommended-hardware-infrastructure-for-running-heavy-jmeter-load-tests